# How to Select All Id in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to select all Id in HTML page. But it's not happening. My code is working at first element.

I used querySelector, querySelectorAll, getElementById, GetElementByClassName but everytime my code run at first Id

```js
//* DOM
let plusIconDOM = document.querySelector(".plusIcon")
let minusIconDOM = document.querySelector(".minusIcon")
let cardTextDOM = document.querySelector("#cardText")

minusIconDOM.addEventListener("click", function() {
  plusIconDOM.classList.remove("d-none")
  cardTextDOM.classList.add("d-none")
  minusIconDOM.classList.add("d-none")
})

plusIconDOM.addEventListener("click", function() {
  minusIconDOM.classList.remove("d-none")
  cardTextDOM.classList.remove("d-none")
  plusIconDOM.classList.add("d-none")
})
```

```html
<card class="card mx-auto">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p class="card-text d-inline" id="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae
      consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
  </div>
</card>
<card class="card mx-auto">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p class="card-text d-inline" id="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae
      consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
  </div>
</card>
<card class="card mx-auto">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p class="card-text d-inline" id="cardText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae
      consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
    <button class="btn float-end">
                        <img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt="">
                    </button>
  </div>
</card>
```

Comment: You cannot use id as a class, id should be unique for one element as explained here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id#:~:text=The%20id%20global%20attribute%20defines%20an%20identifier%20(ID)%20which%20must%20be%20unique%20in%20the%20whole%20document.%20Its%20purpose%20is%20to%20identify%20the%20element%20when%20linking%20(using%20a%20fragment%20identifier)%2C%20scripting%2C%20or%20styling%20(with%20CSS). you can make usage of class to get all the elements that has the defined class

Comment: IDs need to be unique. Just add it as a class

Comment: Beware that querySelectorAll (which seems to be what you want if you want to select every instance of some selector), will result in an ARRAY of dom-elements. So if you want to add Event listeners to all of them, you need to loop over it. IE use smth like domElements.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener(...)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. IDs need to be unique
2. If you delegate you do not NEED IDs

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const isPlus = tgt.matches(".plusIcon");
  const isMinus = tgt.matches(".minusIcon");
  if (!isPlus && !isMinus) return // not one of the plus or minus
  const parent = tgt.closest(".card-body");
  let plusIconDOM = parent.querySelector(".plusIcon");
  let minusIconDOM = parent.querySelector(".minusIcon");
  let cardTextDOM = parent.querySelector(".card-text");
  plusIconDOM.classList.toggle("d-none", isPlus);
  cardTextDOM.classList.toggle("d-none", isMinus);
  minusIconDOM.classList.toggle("d-none", isMinus);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="wrapper">
  <card class="card mx-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p class="card-text d-inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt=""></button><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
  </card>
  <card class="card mx-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p class="card-text d-inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt=""></button><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
  </card>
  <card class="card mx-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-title h5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p class="card-text d-inline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum ea libero expedita debitis dolorum quos non ad sit, impedit dolore aliquam sed rerum dolorem nam provident iusto voluptatum, neque corrupti amet aliquid a rem alias quisquam pariatur! Quae consequatur minima obcaecati iusto eos blanditiis deleniti?</p><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="d-none plusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/1/free-plus-icon-321-thumb.png" alt=""></button><button class="btn float-end"><img width="25px" class="minusIcon" src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-minus-icon-3108-thumb.png" alt=""></button>
    </div>
  </card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't bind addEventListener for every elements. Better approach is

i) wrap the card contents into a single parent Dom.

ii) Add click event Listener for the parent Dom, provide id and purpose attribute for ****+**** and ****-**** icon.

iii) Inside the click handler function do actions based on the **event.target.id** and **event.target.getAttribute("purpose")**.

Hope this will resolve your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
document.querySelectorAll('*[id]')
```